# How can I disable TLSv1.0 with spring boot and embedded tomcat?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I want to de-activate TLSv1.0 with spring boot(release 1.3.3), but it doesn't work if application.yml as below:

`ssl:
    protocol: TLSv1.2
    key-store: /E:/key/server.jks
    key-store-password: serverpkcs12`

I still can access web page if only choose "USE TLS 1.0" in IE.
[See this pic--not work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdvyK.png)

However, if doesn't use embedded tomcat, and add these arguments for Connector located in server.xml, it works fine for me--web page blocked by IE. [See this pic--worked for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJXel.png)

`sslProtocols="TLSv1.2" sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2"`

And I also tried some VM arguments, for exmaple **-Dhttps.protocols="TLSv1.2"**, all of them are useless.

So What can I do for this?

Comment: what about [ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer.html)?

Comment: @bilak  Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 9):

The most transparent and readable way is to explicitly configure the valid TLS protocols in your application configuration file by excluding - of course - the unwanted ones.

e.g. in YAML

```
server.ssl.enabled-protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
```

You can then start your server and check whether TLSv1.0 is working by peforming the following

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:443 -tls1
```

The above connections should be rejected whereas the following two will be accepted and print the certificate's details

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:443 -tls1_1
openssl s_client -connect localhost:443 -tls1_2
```

Comment: Most suitable answer here. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

A way that i found is to set ciphers that are supported only by TLSv1.2. Ex: If you will put in application.yml

```
server.ssl.ciphers:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
```

And the using CURL

> openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -tls1

You will see that request will be ignored / rejected because that cipher that you set in application.yml will validate only TLSv1.2 requests.

Answer (score 2):

My solution is

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainerFactory()
{
    TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();

    factory.addConnectorCustomizers(new TomcatConnectorCustomizer()
    {
        @Override
        public void customize(Connector connector)
        {
            connector.setAttribute("sslProtocols", "TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2");
            connector.setAttribute("sslEnabledProtocols", "TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2");
        }
    });

    return factory;
}
```

And remove  **protocol: TLSv1.2** from application.yml

Answer (score 2):

The answers so far only show how to lock-down TLS to a set of versions not yet considered broken. Since the question was how to **de-activate** a specific version, here's how using at least java 8:

```
  String algs = Security.getProperty("jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms");

  // TODO: null/empty check on algs

  Set<String> disabled =
      Arrays.stream(algs.split(","))
          .map(String::trim)
          .collect(Collectors.toSet());

  // TODO: inject these algs as properties for configurability

  disabled.add("TLSv1");

  algs = String.join(", ", disabled);
  Security.setProperty("jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms", algs);
```

Do this early on in your context initialisation before the Tomcat server is created and to be thorough you should catch `SecurityException` in case there's a policy in place that blocks the `setProperty()` call.

Using this method you benefit from new versions included in the JDK in the future.