# How to upgrade TLS 1.0 to TLS 1.2 on wso2product

Tags: java, ssl, wso2, tls1.2, wso2-business-process

We are trying to upgrade TLS 1.0 to TLS 1.2 version in the WSO2 BPS.Following procedure for upgrading TLS latest version using this link [Reference Link From WSO2](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Configuring+Transport+Level+Security#ConfiguringTransportLevelSecurity-EnablingTLSanddisablingSSLsupport) and our JAVA application is running in JDK 1.8.

1. Open the `<PRODUCT_HOME>/repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml`
   file.
2. Removed the sslProtocol="TLS" attribute and replaced it with
   sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2" as shown below.

> ```
> > <Connector SSLEnabled="true"  port="9443"
> > protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" scheme="https"
> > secure="true" server="WSO2 Carbon Server"
> > sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.2"
> > svns:secretAlias="Server.Service.Connector.keystorePass"/>
> ```

3. Start the server.
4. To verify that the configurations are all set correct or not we execute the following command, `java -jar TestSSLServer.jar localhost 9443` and getting TLS configuration response as TLSv1.2 only,

> ```
> Supported versions: TLSv1.2
> Deflate compression: no
> Supported cipher suites (ORDER IS NOT SIGNIFICANT):
>   TLSv1.2
>      DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
>      DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
>      DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
>      DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
>      TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
>      TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
>      TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
>      TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
>      TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
>      TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
>      TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
>      TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
> ----------------------
> Server certificate(s):
>   501fc1432d87155dc431382aeb843ed558ad61b1: CN=localhost, O=WSO2, L=Mountain View, ST=CA, C=US
> ----------------------
> Minimal encryption strength:     strong encryption (96-bit or more)
> Achievable encryption strength:  strong encryption (96-bit or more)
> BEAST status: protected
> CRIME status: protected
> ```

5. But when we captured the pcap file and in Wireshark it is showing like TLSv1.0 still as shown below:
   [image: PCap File]

### Updated:

We have changed  **`jre/lib/security/java.security`** as per [@user7294900](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57801364/1859369) instruction. 
when we set configuration in that java.security file, we are facing this error message in wso2BPMN. But we can able to view TLS version 1.2 in Wireshark capture with a handshake failure notification. 
[image: wireshack]

Wso2BPMN,

```
Caused by: org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.office365.com:587
at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1398)
at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1423)
at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.MailActivityBehavior.execute(MailActivityBehavior.java:102)
... 192 more
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't send command to SMTP host;
  nested exception is:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1420)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1408)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.ehlo(SMTPTransport.java:847)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:384)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:297)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:105)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:168)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:98)
at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1388)
... 194 more
```

So, is there any configuration required for TLSv1.2 version upgrade.

Comment: Is this Change Cipher Spec message sent from the client or the server? Both should be sending one and this might just be the client indicating that it'd able to speak TLS 1.0 (just guesstimating based on a quick read of the TLS 1.2 RFC, so I might be off).

Comment: @JoachimSauer Is this Change Cipher Spec message sent from the client or the server? It is client-side. we need some clarification about this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to [**disable** TLS below 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32466407/how-to-force-java-server-to-accept-only-tls-1-2-and-reject-tls-1-0-and-tls-1-1-c)

> set the
>
> ```
>  jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms= SSLv2Hello, SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1
> ```
>
> in the file jre/lib/security/java.security on the server.

Also try to reduce your ciphers as [@Dimtri suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38302683/how-can-i-disable-tlsv1-0-with-spring-boot-and-embedded-tomcat/39286817#39286817)

> set ciphers that are supported only by TLSv1.2
>
> ```
> TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
> TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
> TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
> TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
> TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
> TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
> TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
> TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
> ```

Comment: I have modified my question. We are facing issue even after updating these configuration changes.

Comment: @VIVEK-MDU check if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47166425/how-to-force-javamailsenderimpl-to-use-tls1-2

Comment: @VIVEK-MDU maybe it's related to outlook migration to TLS 1.2 https://o365reports.com/2019/02/15/preparing-for-tls-1-2-migration-in-office-365/

Comment: To user7294900-Thanks for your comment. We tried the steps given in that link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47166425/how-to-force-javamailsenderimpl-to-use-tls1-2. But its still going in TLSv1.0 version only.

Comment: @VIVEK-MDU I think this a more issue of serverfault as https://serverfault.com/questions/878400/iis-smtp-and-tls-1-2

Comment: We have tried all the configurations that are mentioned but still facing same issue. We are getting either handshake Failure or TLSv1.0 in wireshark capture.

Answer (score 1):

WSO2 opens many random ports. You can try disabling **TLSv1** and **TLSv1.1** in java.security.
Set below:

> `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms= SSLv2Hello, SSLv3, TLSv1, TLSv1.1`

in the file

> `<PRODUCT_HOME>/jre/lib/security/java.security.`

I tried this for Identity server. You can give it a try for BPS.

Comment: Actually, we tried this method in the BPS. Still it is not working.