# How to disable weak ciphers and TLS v1.0 in tomcat 8.x server?

Tags: tomcat8, tls1.2, owasp, beast

I am trying to fix a security vulnerability that says application should not support TLS v1.0 and also need to disable weak ciphers. How can I achieve this?

The web application in question is running on dedicated a tomcat 8.xx version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I disable TLSv1.0 with spring boot and embedded tomcat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38302683/how-can-i-disable-tlsv1-0-with-spring-boot-and-embedded-tomcat)

Comment: have edited the question ,The web application is using a dedicated tomcat 8